# Not all [GA4] BigQuery Export schema not available via GA4 API?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

I was looking for the number of IDFA /user concents collected per an app release version.

I saw it exists on `[GA4] BigQuery Export schema` [table](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846?hl=en/#is_limited_ad_tracking) (`device.is_limited_ad_tracking`).

But couldn't find it on [GA4](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/).

Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

The API, webUI, and BigQuery export are different sources of data.  Not only do they have different schemas (available dimensions and metrics), when compared, the data often will not match.  This is by design.

This article compares the data sources:
https://analyticscanvas.com/4-ways-to-export-ga4-data/

This article explains why they don't match:
https://analyticscanvas.com/3-reasons-your-ga4-data-doesnt-match/

In most cases, you'll find the solution is to use the BigQuery export.  It has the most rich set of data and doesn't have quota limits.